# Python Logging Filter Levels to Streams

Tags: python, logging

I am setting up a logger for my package.

I have a simple module that simply initiates certain log handlers and formats.

- A File handler
- A console handler ( split into stderr and stdout )
- I also have setup some formatting and filters. I am having trouble with the filters.
- I want to have 2 handlers, one that filters **out** INFO and DEBUG Message ( for the stderr stream) and the other filters out WARNING and above (leaving INFO and DEBUG)

I am not sure I set up my filter classes correctly.I get this error which is not very clear to me:

```
TypeError: unbound method filter() must be called with STDErrFilter instance as first argument (got LogRecord instance instead)
```

here is my code and thanks in advance!:

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import tempfile

class STDOutFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno == logging.INFO | record.levelno == logging.DEBUG

class STDErrFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.levelno == logging.INFO | record.levelno == logging.DEBUG


def start_logbook(log_path=None, log_formatting=None, std_formatting=None, debug=False, clear_previous=True, ):

    log_level = logging.INFO if not debug else logging.DEBUG
    stdout_level = logging.INFO if not debug else logging.DEBUG

    logger  = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    log_path = log_path

    if log_path:

        folder, filename = os.path.split(log_path)

        if folder and not os.path.exists(folder):
            raise IOError("path {0} does not exist!".format(folder))

    else:
        # Setup Temp Log
        log_path = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='tempLog'+'_log_', suffix='.log')

    # Add File Handlers
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
    if clear_previous:
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path, mode='w')

    file_formatting = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-8s --- %(filename)s - %(funcName)s [%(lineno)d] - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatting)

    # Add Console Handler
    error_console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
    error_console_handler.setLevel(stdout_level)
    error_console_handler.addFilter(STDErrFilter)

    info_console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    info_console_handler.setLevel(stdout_level)
    info_console_handler.addFilter(STDOutFilter)


    console_formatting = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s --- %(message)s')
    error_console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatting)
    info_console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatting)

    logger.addHandler(error_console_handler)
    logger.addHandler(info_console_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    return {'log_filepath': os.path.abspath(log_path), 'handlers':[error_console_handler, info_console_handler, file_handler]}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    info = start_logbook("test.log", debug=True)

    log = logging.getLogger("Test Run")

    log.debug("Debug Message goes Here")
    log.info("INFO Message goes Here")
    log.warning("WARNING Message goes Here")
    log.error("ERROR Message goes Here")
    log.critical("Critical Message goes Here")
    log.exception(ValueError("Blarg"))


    logging.shutdown(info['handlers'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured, silly mistake. I needed to instantiate the class in the code when I add the filter instead of passing the object instantiated.

```python
# Add Console Handler
error_console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
error_console_handler.setLevel(stdout_level)
error_console_handler.addFilter(STDErrFilter()) # Problem was here I needed ()

info_console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
info_console_handler.setLevel(stdout_level)
info_console_handler.addFilter(STDOutFilter()) # Problem was here! Needed ()
```